# ¿Cómo reemplazar una lista de nodos?

Tags: javascript, array, lista, dom, nodos

Mi problema es el siguiente: Tengo una lista de productos (No son creados dinámicamente), y realicé un filtro por medio de sus precios y me funciona puesto que lo he comprobado desde consola, sin embargo, no puedo hacer que se visualicen solo esos productos filtrados y los demás sean remplazados, no quiero ocultarlos con la propiedad `display` de js porque de este modo no me funcionaría la paginación.

```
//Filtro por medio de precios
let listProducts = document.getElementById('listProducts'); //Elemento padre que encierra todos mis article
const listProd = Array.from(articles); //Listnode convertida en un array
const btnApply = document.getElementById('btnApply');
if (btnApply) {

    btnApply.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        const txt1 = Number(document.getElementById('txtMin').value);
        const txt2 = Number(document.getElementById('txtMax').value);

        listProd.forEach((article) => {
            let price2 = Number(article.querySelector(":scope .price-wrap .price").textContent.substring(1));

            if (!isNaN(txt1) && !isNaN(txt2)) {
                if (price2 >= txt1 && price2 <= txt2) {

                    listProducts.appendChild(article);
                    console.log(price2)
                }                   
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Lo que hace el código anterior es recorrer el `array` y por cada elemento que encuentre tome el precio y lo convierta en **Number** para realizar la comparación, posteriormente, cuando encuentra los elementos, los agrega al final, sin embargo, necesito que estos últimos reemplacen a los otros existentes. Si hay alguna otra forma de realizarlo, bienvenida es la recomendación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dada a la situación, se puede usar el método `replaceChildren`, la siguiente demostración es similar a lo que estás intentando hacer, solo debes ajustarla a tu ejemplo:

```js
let listProducts = document.getElementById('listProducts'); //Elemento padre que encierra todos mis article
const listProd = document.getElementsByClassName('replaceMe'); //Listnode convertida en un array
const btnApply = document.getElementById('btnApply');
if (btnApply) {

    btnApply.addEventListener('click', function setNodes(){
       //primero los obtenemos
       let newNodes = Array.from(listProd).filter((article) => 
        article.innerHTML !== 'Article C');
        //luego los reemplazamos en una sola operación
       listProducts.replaceChildren(...newNodes);
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<head>
    <title>reemplazando Nodos DOM</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="listProducts">
  <div class="replaceMe">Article A</div>
  <div class="replaceMe">Article B</div>
  <div class="replaceMe">Article C</div>
  <div class="replaceMe">Article D</div>
  <div class="replaceMe">Article E</div>
</div>

<button id="btnApply">Use findandreplace DOM</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Se usó `filter` para obtener una copia del array de nodos ya filtrado, bajo cierta condición, para después, poder pasaralo al método `replaceChildren`:

```
 let newNodes = Array.from(listProd).filter((article) => article.innerHTML !== 'Article C');
```

Tu puedes implementar la lógica original dentro de la función callback de `filter`.

- [Método replaceChildren](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/replaceChildren)
- [Método Filter JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [HTML Collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Tengo una duda, por qué usas los 3 puntos en el replaceChildren? Cómo funcionan?

Comment: Claro, es un operador elipsis, mejor conocido como [operador de propagación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (spread operator), en este ejemplo estamos pasando los elementos del array uno a uno, en vez de pasar el objeto array. También funciona para propiedades de objetos. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias! me ayudaste bastante, voy a investigar más acerca del spread operator

Answer (score 1):

El código funcional implementando la respuesta de @g.4 quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
//Filtro por medio de precios
const btnApply = document.getElementById('btnApply');
if (btnApply) {

    btnApply.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        const txt1 = Number(document.getElementById('txtMin').value);
        const txt2 = Number(document.getElementById('txtMax').value);
        
        let newNodes = listProd.filter((article) => {
            let price2 = Number(article.querySelector(":scope .price-wrap .price").textContent.substring(1));

            if (!isNaN(txt1) && !isNaN(txt2)) {
                if (price2 >= txt1 && price2 <= txt2) {
                    return article;
                }
            }
        });
        //Elimina los nodos secundarios, y agrega una nueva lista de nodos
        listProducts.replaceChildren(...newNodes);
    });
}
```

Al contener `price2` la referencia al padre, facilita que este sea devuelto y se pueda capturar en `replaceChildren()`